# Is it possible to make android and or IOS phones microphone and transmit to Bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

I want "convert" the phone to microphone, 
When I talk to the phone, and the phone is connect to Which speaker 
i want hear the sound on speaker.
In other words to convert the phone to microphone.

my question if its passible?
or its possible Only one of the platforms?

or not.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to use your phone as a microphone to transmit speech, on Android you can do it if you dig for some good tutorials, and I am not sure about the iOS it depends on it's permissions